# Restoring files to upgraded Ubuntu version using Deja Dup

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, backup, deja-dup

I am planning on upgrading my Ubuntu version from 14.04 to 16.04. I have a bunch of Deja Dup backup files for my 14.04 system.

Suppose I put them on an external drive, something goes wrong with the upgrade, and I lose some files but somehow get 16.04 working. Would I be able to restore the missing files on 16.04 using my 14.04 backup files?

As a side note, the only folder I have backed up is my home folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, yes, this should work just fine. You can restore individual files or restore your entire backup.

For individual files:

```
Browse to the folder containing the file you lost.
Click File ▸ Restore Missing Files….
When the Restore dialog appears, it will scan for files that are in the backup but no longer in the folder.
When you see the file you want to restore appear, select it and click Forward.
Review your selections and click Restore.
```

To restore the entire backup, use the backups GUI and select restore and then follow the instructions there.

If you pay attention during your install, you can leave your home directory untouched with the upgrade or install in place options.

If you're looking to do a super fresh and clean install, back up your home folder directly to an external drive ( just to be safe ) and then you can do an "erase and install" and if for some reason you cant get the deja dup backup to work, you have an extra set.... Always better to be safe than sorry when it comes to sensitive data.